# Trying to build a rust program using the gtk4 crate for x86_64-pc-windows-gnu fails with missing libraries

Tags: rust, gtk, cross-compiling, mingw-w64

I'm trying to cross compile a GTK4 based application, however no matter what I've tried I keep running into errors about missing libraries, and I can't figure out how to add these libraries to my distro. I've noticed that the AUR and Fedora packages have packages specifically for GTK, while Ubuntu does not, so I'm wondering if I'd have to manually download them, or if there is possibly some other repository I can add to APT to get them.

On Kubuntu 22.04, using rustc 1.63.0, mingw-w64 8.0.0-1.

Running `cargo build --target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` almost immediately fails outputting

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `...`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `.../self-avoiding-walk/target/debug/build/.../build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=..._NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:warning=pkg-config has not been configured to support cross-compilation.

  Install a sysroot for the target platform and configure it via
  PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR and PKG_CONFIG_PATH, or install a
  cross-compiling wrapper for pkg-config and set it via
  PKG_CONFIG environment variable.
```

for `gtk4-sys, gsk4-sys, gdk4-sys, gio-sys, cairo-sys-rs, glib-sys, pango-sys, gdk-pixbuf-sys, graphene-sys, gobject-sys`

and setting `PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/` gets further, but still breaks, outputting

```
  = note: /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgtk-4: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lpangocairo-1.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lpango-1.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lharfbuzz: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lcairo-gobject: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lcairo: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgraphene-1.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgio-2.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgtk-4: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lpangocairo-1.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lpango-1.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lharfbuzz: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lcairo-gobject: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lcairo: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgraphene-1.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgio-2.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgraphene-1.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgtk-4: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lpangocairo-1.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lpango-1.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lharfbuzz: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lcairo-gobject: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lcairo: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgraphene-1.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgio-2.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lpango-1.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lharfbuzz: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lcairo-gobject: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lcairo: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgio-2.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0: No such file or directory
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've tried `cross build --target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` with default settings but it failed in seemingly the exact same way as `cargo` did.

Builds fine for `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`

Here is my Cargo.toml for reference.

```
[package]
name = "self-avoiding-walk"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
gtk = { version = "0.4.8", package = "gtk4" }
rand = "0.8.5"
```

### Edit:

I found a docker container called [gtk4-cross](https://github.com/MGlolenstine/gtk4-cross) that seems to do what I want after a bit of manual effort, as the instructions aren't exactly accurate. Manually pulled the latest rust image from DockerHub using `docker pull mglolenstine/gtk4-cross:rust-gtk-4.6` since I had 4.6, and then run `` docker run -ti -v `pwd`:/mnt mglolenstine/gtk4-cross:rust-gtk-4.6 ``. From there the instructions are fine, just run `build` from the interactive shell.

However, although it now compiles, it still will not run because the necessary libraries are dynamically linked rather than statically, so it expects the user to install glib, cairo... etc. This is not the desired behaviour, and I'm unsure how to force it to include the static libraries I have installed rather than the dynamically linked ones.

Comment: GTK does not support being statically linked into applications. You'll have to ship GTK/etc as shared libraries together with your application.

Comment: @SebastianDröge and how would that be done then, would they just be put in the same directory as the executable? Would I copy the DLLs from somewhere like the mingw lib dir or would they be in my build dir somewhere?

Comment: That depends on where you got your GTK/etc libraries from, and how you want to distribute your application. The latter is just the same as how you would distribute any other library with your application on Windows. You could put the DLLs into the same directory as your EXE, you could adjust the PATH environment variable accordingly, ...

That all has nothing to do with GTK anymore but is a general question about application distribution on Windows.